# ansi c: converting argv into int

Tags: c

hi i wanted to convert the argv in ansi-c into int. i am not sure of a few things...

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

let's assume my program is run as follows ./a input1 input2.

let's assume in this case that my input1 = 12345 and input2=67890

i don't want to use atoi. i wanted to convert it all by my own. for example when i call the argv[1] is it equal to only "12345" or is it possible that it may be "  12345 "? i.e. can it have spaces from any of its sides?

the problem with atoi and sscanf is that if my input1="0" and input1="abc"

then both atoi and sscanf would return 0, if i am wrong correct me... thanks!

Comment: Use strtol() instead of atoi() - it lets you detect that space.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you don't want to use `atoi`?

Comment: This isn't homework by any chance? It's okay to ask homework questions, just mark them as such.

Comment: Then why don't you want to use the built-in `atoi` (or better, `strtol`)?

Comment: @Peter With strtol() you can determine which character caused the conversion to fail (in this case  a space) - you can't do that with atoi().

Comment: @Neil: I think Peter was asking why the OP doesn't want to use atoi; we all seem to know about sscanf vs atoi vs strol. Chris's guess (hand-roll) sounds likely!

Comment: Can I upvote a comment for agreeing with me? Is that ethical?

Comment: It's thoroughly possible for an argument to have leading or trailing spaces: try `printf(">%s<\n",argv[1]);` with `a.out "       x      "` to see this in action.

Answer (score 6):

String-to-integer conversion in C standard library is performed by `strtol` function (or other functions from `strto...` group). Forget about `atoi` and `sscanf` - these functions provide no means for error detection and/or overflow protection.

Whether or not you may receive spaces around the argument depends on the system-specific conventions for passing leading and trailing spaces and, of course, on what was actually passed by the user. Normally, different OSes provide a way to pass these spaces if the user wants to do so. So it is really up to you to decide whether you consider such input correct or erroneous.

`strtol` will essentially allow (and ignore) leading and trailing spaces. Same is true for `atoi` and `sscanf`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this by yourself, you need to loop through the string, checking that each character is a digit. Let's assume you're using ASCII:

```
char *str = "624532";
int index = 0;
int value = 0;
while(str[index]) {
    if(str[index] >= 48 && str[index] < 58) {
        value = (value * 10) + (str[index] - 48);
    }
    index++;
}
```

Make sure you use a null-terminated string or this will run forever. It's also not going to be very helpful if your input is malformed.

Comment: Let's not assume you're using ASCII, but that the C standard guarantees that '0' through '9' will be consecutive, and that using '0' instead of 48 will be both more portable and more readable. But +1 for providing code that "works with caveats" and leaving the OP to learn how the code works in order to tweak it to his/her specific needs.

Comment: Yup, that was my goal. You could also trivially adapt it to handle non consecutive digits and (less trivially) UTF8/16, but I felt that a basic outline would suffice. The lack of details leads me to suspect it is homework.

Comment: The example code doesn't deal with leading or trailing spaces - which of course constitute part of the exercise.

Comment: Very true, I consider that part of malformed, perhaps I should have said it only works if your input is exactly a number, on the other hand coming from the command line, space is rather unusual. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

How about [scanf](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/3/scanf) then?

Comment: `sscanf` would be better, since the OP wants to read input from `argv` (a string), but since the `*scanf` functions use `strtol` to do their conversion, and `atoi` uses `strtol` too, the OP probably doesn't want to use this. I assumed (s)he wanted to hand-roll an `atoi` (for learning, I presume).

Comment: I don't think the scanf() functions necessarily use strtol() et al - their error handling is (a lot) worse than the error handling in strtol().